# Undefined type Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-passport

I followed the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport) to install the Passport service in Laravel. However when I want to use HasApiToken in my user model I get the error Undefined type 'Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens'.

User.php:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;
```

Composer.json

```json
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
        "laravel/passport": "^8.4",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^2.0"
    },
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 9):

You need to restart/refresh your editor/IDE. (It'll load all the updated files.)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider your tone when addressing others on this forum. Some remarks, while they might seem trivial to you, could be taken seriously or as impolite.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.  For some reason, the package was not added to the config/app.php file.  I added Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class to my providers in config/app.php and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue and it was resolved by doing the following:

1- update the laravel/passport package by deleting it from config app.php then

run

`composer require laravel/passport` and `composer update`

2- install the following packages

run

`composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle`

and

`composer require symfony/psr-http-message-bridge`

Comment: there is no package inside config->app.php. i also get the same issue

Comment: the laravel passport package should appear in config folder if installed successfully